# Hibernate HQL Projection Issue with Set Using AliasToBeanResultTransformer

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, projection, resulttransformer

I am having a problem with [Hibernate HQL Projection](http://levelup.lishman.com/hibernate/hql/projection.php) using the [AliasToBeanResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html), basically the result I am trying to return isn't being mapped properly to the bean, here is the situation:

The HQL query that I am using is this:

```sql
select entity.categoryTypes as categoryTypes from nz.co.doltech.ims.server.entities.IncidentEntity entity where (entity.id = :id105019)
```

I want to get the `CategoryType`'s from the `IncidentEntity` based on its join relationship. This works fine when I'm not attempting to use any transformer on it. `categoryTypes` is a Set and the transformer keeps trying to check the Method's parameter types and fails because instead of finding a `CategoryTypeEntity` it finds a `java.util.Set` as if its trying to map a single `CategoryTypeEntity` into the `categoryTypes` field. I would have thought that because its a Set it would pull the data out as a `Set` and then try map it to the `categoryTypes` field. Apparently not though.

```java
@javax.persistence.Entity(name = "incidents")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
public class IncidentEntity implements Entity {

    ...

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "incident_categorytype", joinColumns = { 
            @JoinColumn(name = "incident_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "categorytype_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) 
    })
    private Set<CategoryTypeEntity> categoryTypes = new HashSet<CategoryTypeEntity>();

    ...

    public Set<CategoryTypeEntity> getCategoryTypes() {
        return categoryTypes;
    }
    public void setCategoryTypes(Set<CategoryTypeEntity> categoryTypes) {
        this.categoryTypes = categoryTypes;
    }
}
```

Here is the call I make:

```java
Query query = session.createQuery("select entity.categoryTypes as categoryTypes from nz.co.doltech.ims.server.entities.IncidentEntity entity " + 
                                  "where (entity.id = :id105019)")

query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(IncidentEntity.class));

return query.list();
```

The exceptions I get are:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyAccessException: IllegalArgumentException occurred while calling setter of nz.co.doltech.ims.server.entities.IncidentEntity.categoryTypes
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
```

And the hibernate log message is:

```
Jun 27, 2014 12:32:11 AM org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter set
SEVERE: IllegalArgumentException in class: nz.co.doltech.ims.server.entities.IncidentEntity, setter method of property: categoryTypes
Jun 27, 2014 12:32:11 AM org.hibernate.property.BasicPropertyAccessor$BasicSetter set
SEVERE: expected type: java.util.Set, actual value: nz.co.doltech.ims.server.entities.CategoryTypeEntity
```

**Using Hibernate 3.6.10**

Can anyone see what is going on here? It really doesn't seem like normal behavior, perhaps I have done something wrong. Would appreciate any help I can get!

**UPDATE:** This is strange, not directly related to the issue. When I have hibernates use_query_cache property set to true I keep getting the projection result as null in the AliasToBeanResultTransformer (then the result returns as null (or [null, null, null] depending on how many are returned. I think this might be a bug? In regards to the issue at hand, when I remove the result transformer it returns 3 `CategoryTypeEntites` as expected. When its added I get one CategoryTypeEntity that's being processed in the Transformers transformTuple method. Really confused about both of these issues.

Cheers,
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manage to resolve this issue by rewriting the AliasToBeanResultTransformer class. It will not insert into a collection if the collection types match and the collections generic type match. I also found a great nested bean transformer make by [samiandoni](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18731258/1741601) that will allow me to map nested projection values too :) Here is how I implemented it for anyone else having this same issue:

```java
@SuppressWarnings({"serial","rawtypes"})
public class AliasToBeanResultTransformer implements ResultTransformer, Serializable {

    // IMPL NOTE : due to the delayed population of setters (setters cached
    //      for performance), we really cannot properly define equality for
    //      this transformer

    private final Class resultClass;
    private boolean isInitialized;
    private String[] aliases;

    private Setter[] setters;
    private Getter[] getters;

    public AliasToBeanResultTransformer(Class resultClass) {
        if ( resultClass == null ) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( "resultClass cannot be null" );
        }
        isInitialized = false;
        this.resultClass = resultClass;
    }

    @Override
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        Object result;

        try {
            if ( ! isInitialized ) {
                initialize( aliases );
            }
            else {
                check( aliases );
            }

            result = resultClass.newInstance();

            for ( int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++ ) {
                Setter setter = setters[i];
                if ( setter != null ) {
                    Class paramType = setter.getMethod().getParameterTypes()[0];

                    if(paramType != null) {
                        Object obj = tuple[i];
                        // Check if parameter is a collection
                        if(!obj.getClass().equals(paramType) && isCollection(paramType)) {
                            insertToList(result, obj, getters[i], aliases[i]);
                        }
                        else {
                            setter.set( result, obj, null );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch ( InstantiationException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException( "Could not instantiate resultclass: " + resultClass.getName() );
        }
        catch ( IllegalAccessException e ) {
            throw new HibernateException( "Could not instantiate resultclass: " + resultClass.getName() );
        }

        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public List transformList(List collection) {
        return collection;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private boolean insertToList(Object result, Object obj, Getter getter, String alias) {
        Class genClass;
        try {
            genClass = ReflectUtils.getGenericType(resultClass.getDeclaredField(alias));

            // Check if the collection can take the obj
            if(genClass.equals(obj.getClass())) {
                Collection collection = (Collection) getter.get(result);
                collection.add(obj);
                return true;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | SecurityException e) {}

        return false;
    }

    private void initialize(String[] aliases) {
        PropertyAccessor propertyAccessor = new ChainedPropertyAccessor(
                new PropertyAccessor[] {
                        PropertyAccessorFactory.getPropertyAccessor( resultClass, null ),
                        PropertyAccessorFactory.getPropertyAccessor( "field" )
                }
        );
        this.aliases = new String[ aliases.length ];
        setters = new Setter[ aliases.length ];
        getters = new Getter[ aliases.length ];
        for ( int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++ ) {
            String alias = aliases[ i ];
            if ( alias != null ) {
                this.aliases[ i ] = alias;
                setters[ i ] = propertyAccessor.getSetter( resultClass, alias );
                getters[ i ] = propertyAccessor.getGetter( resultClass, alias );
            }
        }
        isInitialized = true;
    }

    private void check(String[] aliases) {
        if ( ! Arrays.equals( aliases, this.aliases ) ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "aliases are different from what is cached; aliases=" + Arrays.asList( aliases ) +
                            " cached=" + Arrays.asList( this.aliases ) );
        }
    }

    private boolean isCollection(Class clazz) {
        return Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if ( this == o ) {
            return true;
        }
        if ( o == null || getClass() != o.getClass() ) {
            return false;
        }

        AliasToBeanResultTransformer that = ( AliasToBeanResultTransformer ) o;

        if ( ! resultClass.equals( that.resultClass ) ) {
            return false;
        }
        if ( ! Arrays.equals( aliases, that.aliases ) ) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        int result = resultClass.hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + ( aliases != null ? Arrays.hashCode( aliases ) : 0 );
        return result;
    }
}
```

You will need to implement this RefectUtil method too:

```java
public static Class<?> getGenericType(Field field) {
    ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType();
    return (Class<?>) type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}
```

Then you can make it work with samiandoni's transformer too (just ensure its using your edited AliasToBeanResultTransformer class):

```java
/**
 * @author samiandoni
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public class AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer implements ResultTransformer, Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8047276133980128266L;

    private final Class<?> resultClass;

    public AliasToBeanNestedResultTransformer(Class<?> resultClass) {
        this.resultClass = resultClass;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {

        Map<Class<?>, List<?>> subclassToAlias = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<?>>();
        List<String> nestedAliases = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < aliases.length; i++) {
                String alias = aliases[i];
                if (alias.contains(".")) {
                    nestedAliases.add(alias);

                    String[] sp = alias.split("\\.");
                    String fieldName = sp[0];
                    String aliasName = sp[1];

                    Class<?> subclass = resultClass.getDeclaredField(fieldName).getType();

                    if (!subclassToAlias.containsKey(subclass)) {
                        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();
                        list.add(new ArrayList<Object>());
                        list.add(new ArrayList<String>());
                        list.add(fieldName);
                        subclassToAlias.put(subclass, list);
                    }
                    ((List<Object>)subclassToAlias.get(subclass).get(0)).add(tuple[i]);
                    ((List<String>)subclassToAlias.get(subclass).get(1)).add(aliasName);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            throw new HibernateException( "Could not instantiate resultclass: " + resultClass.getName() );
        }

        Object[] newTuple = new Object[aliases.length - nestedAliases.size()];
        String[] newAliases = new String[aliases.length - nestedAliases.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < aliases.length; j++) {
            if (!nestedAliases.contains(aliases[j])) {
                newTuple[i] = tuple[j];
                newAliases[i] = aliases[j];
                ++i;
            }
        }

        ResultTransformer rootTransformer = new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(resultClass);
        Object root = rootTransformer.transformTuple(newTuple, newAliases);

        for (Class<?> subclass : subclassToAlias.keySet()) {
            ResultTransformer subclassTransformer = new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(subclass);
            Object subObject = subclassTransformer.transformTuple(
                ((List<Object>)subclassToAlias.get(subclass).get(0)).toArray(), 
                ((List<Object>)subclassToAlias.get(subclass).get(1)).toArray(new String[0])
            );

            PropertyAccessor accessor = PropertyAccessorFactory.getPropertyAccessor("property");
            accessor.getSetter(resultClass, (String)subclassToAlias.get(subclass).get(2)).set(root, subObject, null);
        }

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public List transformList(List collection) {
        return collection;
    }
}
```